# ios 8.1: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm getting the following error when compile swift application (iOS 8.1)

> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'

at "class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate" line

I've just checked few posts here but no one helps me to solve this problem.

Here's the code of ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
var tableDescription: [String] = []
var tableNumbers: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.populateView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return tableDescription.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell: CollViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollViewCell
    
    cell.lblDescription.text = tableDescription[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblNumber.text = tableNumbers[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
 }
```

Comment: which Xcode version are you using? are you getting this in the latest Xcode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for typos in your code, Like - use "numberOfItemsInSection"instead numberOfItemInSection.