# Even though I added method for UICollectionViewDataSource it gives me an error

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

```
    //
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  CollectionViewTry 
    //
   //  Created by Shivam Agrawal on 25/03/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Shivam Agrawal. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)






        /*   print(BigBox.count)
         for i in 0...80{
         print("\(BigBox[i].identifier) \(BigBox[i].ColID) \(BigBox[i].RowID) \(BigBox[i].SmallBox) \(BigBox[i].sbCount)")
         }*/
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 14
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    return cell
}
```

[ios 8.1: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049045/ios-8-1-type-viewcontroller-does-not-conform-to-protocol-uicollectionviewdat)

My question is similar as above one. I tried and googled but couldn't find how to fix error in my code. Even though I have added methods it says that doesn't conform to protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- Both signatures of the data source methods are wrong for Swift 3. The correct signatures are:

  ```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  ```
- As already mentioned in Roope's answer the data source methods must be **inside** the class.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to swift hence I am doing silly mistakes and trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The functions are outside your class. Thus, they're not methods of said class. Move them inside it.